# External image upload button for React TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I'm trying to make an external image upload button like so:

[image: image upload button]

Now, I already have images_upload_handler defined for TinyMCE for its image upload function(it's already functional if I click on the default image upload button inside the toolbar). How do I refer to that handler function by clicking on this external button?

I made a separate component for the external image upload button. And my TinyMCE component looks like this(notice the images_upload_handler):

```
<TinyMCE
    className={this.props.className || ''}
    ref={this.props.editorRef}
    content={this.props.value}
    config={{
        setup: (editor) => {
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
            // error out if max is reached
            const { maxAttachmentSizeBytes, attachments } = this.props;
            const file = blobInfo.blob();
            if (file.size > maxAttachmentSizeBytes || _.sum(_.map(attachments, f => isNaN(f.fileSize) ? 0 : parseInt(f.fileSize))) + file.size > maxAttachmentSizeBytes) {
                failure(I18n.t('Your email provider limits attachments to: ') + getFormattedSize(maxAttachmentSizeBytes));
                return;
            }

            window.tinymce.activeEditor._skinLoaded = true;
            let xhr, formData;
            const config = getConfig(this.props.env);

            }).catch(() => {
                window.tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(window.tinymce.activeEditor.getContent().replace(/<img.*?src="(data:|blob:).*?(>|\/>)/g, ''));
                failure('You are not logged in.');
            });
        }.bind(this),
........
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made it work. I finally found the path to the onClick function for the image upload button: Window.tinyMCE.activeEditor.buttons.image.onclick.

```
{window.tinymce.activeEditor && this.props.showImageUpload &&
<div className="attachments-button" onClick={window.tinyMCE.activeEditor.buttons.image.onclick}>
<ImageIcon fill='#666666'/> <span id="attachment-label">{this.props.showLabel ? 'Upload an image' : ''}</span>
</div>}
```